# Fast irreversible transformation/compression of short messages using a secret

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, keys, compression-function

I'm looking for a very fast function $f(m, k) $ that takes a 64-bit integer $m$ and a fixed secret key $k$ of virtually any size (generated by a CSPRNG) and turns them into a 64- or 32-bit integer $ r $, with a few additional requirements:

1. $ r $ must depend on both $m$ and $ k $ and be reasonably well-distributed
2. if a pair of $ m $ and $ r $ is known, it should not be possible to efficiently calculate $ k $ or produce $ f(m_1, k) = r_1 $
3. $ r $ will be used as a kind of a key or tag associated with $ m $, but it doesn't have to uniquely identify $ m $ (i.e. the existence of $ m_1 $, $ m_2 $ such that $f(m_1, k) = f(m_2, k) = r $ is completely normal), so I'm not too concerned about collisions

IOW, I need a way to quickly and irreversibly transform/compress/scramble a fixed-size integer (possibly shortening it) using a *secret*.

I *think* ideally this would be solved by a keyed cryptographic hash function like Blake* or Siphash. For example, Siphash was specifically
designed to work well on small inputs and maintain key secrecy, and it's currently used in CPython for hash table lookups.
Performance-wise Siphash-2-4 is maybe tolerable for my use case and seems to check all the boxes, but since I only need to process a 64-bit integer, it feels like an overkill and I'm still interested in anything more lightweight.

I've also looked at several non-cryptographic hash functions and their performance is very appealing, but I'm afraid many of them will fail the second requirement I listed (especially if I feed them $ k || m $, which simplifies brute-force attack in case of FNV-1A and Murmurhash3). [XXH3](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/releases) explicitly lets me provide a `secret` to customize hash values, and it seems to outperform any other decent hash function in existence, but it's also explicitly non-cryptographic, so unfortunately I'm not sure if it can provide the same level of security as Siphash, even for a use case as simple as mine.

I've also tried creating my own mixing/compression function (which most likely is not secure) and considered using a mixing/compression function from an existing algorithm (most likely not designed to be used separately from the original algorithm).

Am I missing a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What about something like $\text{SHA}(m||k)$ truncated to 64/32 bits? Or the full [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) business if necessary?

Comment: @PaulUszak unfortunately, according to [some benchmarks](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash#benchmarks), SHA1 is several times slower than Blake3, Siphash, and most non-cryptographic hash functions. I would prefer something that's as fast or faster than Siphash

Comment: [Discohash](https://github.com/c9fe/discohash) seems quick, but not sure  if it's safe or tested much.  Must the hash function itself be keyed?

Comment: I'm open to a different reading of requirement 2 than in [my answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87426/555), if it's stated an order of magnitude of the number of pairs $(m,r)$ an adversary can gather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first part of this answer, I restrict to reading requirement 2 as "*if **one** pair $(m,r)$ is known…*", and assume that $k$ is chosen at random. I entirely disregard security when an adversary knows ***two*** distinct pairs $(m,r)$, or when related keys $k$ are used.

The following construction uses the [Galois Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) $(\mathbb F_{2^{64}},\oplus,\otimes)$, with some irreducible polynomial¹:

$$f:\{0,1\}^{64}\times\{0,1\}^{128}\to\{0,1\}^{64}\\
(m,k)\mapsto (k_1\otimes m)\oplus k_0=r\\
\text{ where }\ k_1\mathbin\|k_0=k\ \text{ and }\ |k_0|=64=|k_1|$$

Given $(m,r)$ and $(m_1,r_1)$ with $m\ne m_1$, there exists a unique² key $k$ with $f(m,k)=r$ and $f(m_1,k)=r_1$. It follows that the construction perfectly meets it's security objective, regardless of the computational power of adversaries.

Note: For any fixed $k$ with $k_1\ne0$, there are no collisions.

Note: We wan restrict to a smaller output by removing any number of bits from the the result. We can correspondingly shorten the key $k$ by removing the bits of $k$ (in $k_0$) that do not influence the result.

Note: Computation of $f$ is simple and efficient on a CPU with built-in support for binary field arithmetic, including most modern x86 CPUs, which have [carry-less multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLMUL_instruction_set). There's little point to this method otherwise.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#if OPTIMIZED // for Intel Westmere (2010), AMD Jaguar (2013) and later.
#include <immintrin.h>
inline uint64_t f(uint64_t m, const uint64_t k[2]) {
  __m128i u,v;
  u.m128i_u64[0] = k[1];
  u.m128i_u64[1] = 27;                  // X**64 + x**4 + x**3 + x + 1
  v.m128i_u64[0] = m;
  v = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(u, v, 0);    // u.m128i_u64[0] * v.m128i_u64[0]
  u = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(u, v, 17);   // u.m128i_u64[1] * v.m128i_u64[1]
  return k[0] ^ v.m128i_u64[0] ^ u.m128i_u64[0];
}
#else // no _mm_clmulepi64_si128
#pragma warning(disable : 4146)         // silence silly compiler's warning
uint64_t f2(uint64_t m, const uint64_t k[2]) {
  uint64_t a = k[1], x = (m & -(a & 1)) ^ k[0];
  a = (a >> 1) | (1ull << 63);          // insert sentinel
  do                                    // 63 times
    x ^= (m = (27 & -(m >> 63)) ^ (m + m)) & -(a & 1);
  while ((a >>= 1) != 1);
  return x;
}
#endif
```

---

Now I read requirement 2 as "*if **some number of** pairs $(m,r)$ are known…*". If said number is large (larger than we are willing to process 64-bit key blocks), we can no longer build a perfectly secure system.

What the question asks can be nicely solved with a 64-bit block cipher, but then there is the question of choosing it. [TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm)? [RC5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5)? [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher))? [Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(cipher))? [Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(cipher))? [Speck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher))? One of the [lightweight crypto candidates](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.IR.8268)? Any will do. And then we could venture into something custom.

---

¹ e.g. $x^{64}+x^4+x^3+x+1$, see Joerg Arndt's [Binary irreducible polynomials with lowest-most possible set bits](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/lowbit-irredpoly.txt). This polynomial happens to also be [primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)), but we do not need that property.

² Proof: that $k$ can be found as $k_1\gets(r\oplus r_1)\oslash (m\oplus m_1)$, $k_0\gets(k_1\otimes m)\oplus r$, $k\gets k_1\mathbin\|k_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for an elaborate answer! The method involving irreducible polynomial is very interesting and I *may* actually be able to use it, but yes, the second requirement should have been "if some number of pairs $ (m, r) $ are known..." -- I apologise for the ambiguity and my delayed response. Still, thank you for considering both interpretations and providing me with more options to read up on and use. Much appreciated!